# CentOS7にて、Dockerのメモリ制限を解除する方法が分かりません

Tags: linux, docker, centos

以下のサイトなどでは、Docker Desktopを用いてDockerで使用できるメモリの上限値を変更していますが、CentOSではDocker Desktopを利用できないため、どうすれば、初期設定で2GBとなっているメモリ容量を変更することが出来るのでしょうか？

**参考サイト:**
[メモリ使用量を引き上げたらDockerの動作がサクサクになった話](https://techtechmedia.com/docker-trouble-solution/#:%7E:text=%E5%8F%82%E8%80%83-,%E3%83%87%E3%83%95%E3%82%A9%E3%83%AB%E3%83%88%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AF%E3%83%A1%E3%83%A2%E3%83%AA%E3%81%AF%E5%88%B6%E9%99%90%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B,%E3%81%AB%E5%88%B6%E9%99%90%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99%E3%80%82)

Comment: 「Centosでは～初期設定で2GBとなっている」の根拠を提示してください。

Comment: windowsとmacで2GBなので、Linuxも2GBだと思ったのですが違うのでしょうか？

Comment: 制限を解除したいのであればその制限についてまずご自分でお調べください。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Docker Desktop](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/) は、 Linux 仮想環境を仮想マシン(Virtual Machine; VM)上に構築してそこで Docker を動かす仕組みになっています。

質問されている設定値は、このVMが利用するリソースの上限を定めるものです。

他方、Linuxで[Docker Engine](https://docs.docker.com/engine/)を利用する場合、VM上で動かすわけではないので、これに相当する設定はありません。
一般的なインストール手順でインストールしてそのまま動作させているのであれば、ホストのリソースを際限なく利用できていると思います。

(Docker Desktop for Linux を利用するのであれば、 Windows/Mac で利用する場合と同じく [VM上で動く](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/linux-install/#why-docker-desktop-for-linux-runs-a-vm)ので[同様の設定](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/settings/linux/#advanced)がある、ようです。)

Answer (score 2):

参照している記事はあくまで Mac 向けであることは注意が必要です。

---

"docker memory limit default linux" で検索すると、例えば以下のページがヒットします。

[How to increase/check default memory Docker has on Linux? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62649255/2322778)

[回答の一つ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62655408/2322778) によれば、Linux 版の Docker であればホストのメモリを制限なく使えるとのことです。

> On native Linux, Docker can use all available host memory.

`-m` オプション等を使い、必要に応じて任意の制限をかけることは可能です。

[Limit a container’s access to memory ｜Runtime options with Memory, CPUs, and GPUs](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/#limit-a-containers-access-to-memory)